# django_filters.FilterSet with Or Operator

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filters

i'd like to try an **OR statement** with django_filters.FilterSet, to create a "filter only field" (ie: doesn't exist in the model). This field should check if the filter value match one of the models "real field" (two of them)

Here is my Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id          = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    cat         = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='projects', db_index=True, default=None, null=True)
    cat_main    = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, null=True)
    category_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, null=True)
    country     = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)
    added       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is the code i tried to achieve this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class ProjectCatFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    category = django_filters.MethodFilter(name='category', action='category_or_filter')
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['cat_main', 'category_id']

    def category_or_filter(self, queryset, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(category_id=value) | Q(cat_main=value)
        )
```

And here is the call that should return me either Project where "category" match "cat_main" or "category_id"

```
from server.ks.models import Project
projects = Project.objects.filter(category=1)
for p in projects:
    print p.name, p.id, p.cat_main, p.category_id
```

but i get this error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: name, cat, cat_id, cat_main, category_id, country, added, modified

Then what is the correct/best way for Project.objects.filter(category=1) to return projects that match category_id OR main_cat fields (with FilterSet or not)?

Comment: probably the reason that you haven't got an answer yet is because you are using a third party package to execute a query. Do yo really need that package? A lot of django users here are probably unfamiliar with it since django's ORM provides fantastic query filtering capabilities third party plugins are rarely needed.

Comment: I am obviously open to any suggestion without the django_filters package as long as `Project.objects.filter(category=1)` return me projects that match category_id OR main_cat fields.

Comment: So why aren't you just doing Project.objects.filter(Q(pk=1) | Q(cat_main=whatever_you_want_it_to_be)) ?

Comment: i wont make the call directly, it is linked to a django rest framework from my client, and i need to match some specifications which force me to do this pattern: `SomeModel.objects.filter({field1:value, field2:value})`

Comment: because the client is the king and i must not touch the rest framework myself ^^ only answer to his request with the designed pattern

Comment: and what makes you think you can use built in django filters with DRF?

Comment: I already do for project name field with a lookup expr "icontains". Actually it's not DRF that is using django filters. DRF calls models.Manager with basic filter syntax (ie: not with Q queries). It works in this case because 'name' is a "true" field of my Model.

Answer (score 0):

django-filter's `FilterSet` is conceptually similar to Django's builtin `ModelForm`s.

- `ModelForm`s generate a form used for creating or updating instances of a model class.
- `FilterSet`s generate a form that is used for constructing an orm query.

Your example call doesn't work because it doesn't call the FilterSet - there is no `category` field to filter on.

To test the filterset manually:

```py
from server.ks.models import Project
from server.ks.filters import ProjectFilter

filterset = ProjectFilter(data={'category': '1'}, queryset=Project.objects.all())

for p in filterset.qs:
    print p.name, p.id, p.cat_main, p.category_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i guess my question is far from explicit in the main description (i've just updated it accordingly). My true problematic is to find the best way that make: Project.objects.filter(category=1) returning projects that match category_id OR main_cat fields.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the ViewSet code. You say that DRF is doing the filtering itself, however DRF actually delegates to a number of filter backends, including one for django-filter. Are you using a `filter_class` or `filter_fields`? `filter_fields` just automatically generates a `filter_class` for you. If you've set `filter_class` to ProjectFilter, then `/api/projects?category=1` should result in `Project.objects.filter(Q(category_id=value) | Q(cat_main=value))`.